# Unable to Export HighCharts from IE

Tags: highcharts

When I export my graphs from IE, the exported file is not coming up with a file extension. 
This was working until a couple of days Ago. 
Has anyone else seen this behavior? is there a fix for this? 
i am able to export fine from Google Chrome.

Comment: According to topic in the fogbugz, we're investingating this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed and working now for the public export server.